# Need to prove if two vector spaces are isomorphic, then they have the same dimension? ("Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

The following proposition is in this book:

> 3.59 **Dimension shows whether vector spaces are isomorphic**
> Two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

The author proved if two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ are isomorphic, then they have the same dimension.

Two isomorphic vector spaces have the same algebraic structure.
Do we really need to prove if two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ are isomorphic, then they have the same dimension?

---

If we consider two vector spaces $U$ and $V$ are the same vector space (we consider two canonically isomorphic vector spaces are the same vector space), then any property that holds for $U$ also must hold for $V$ because $U=V$.

If we consider two vector spaces $U$ and $V$ are not the same vector space, but they are isomorphic, then I think any algebraic property that holds for $U$ also holds for $V$ because $U$ and $V$ have the same algebraic structure.

When we can declare that we consider $U$ and $V$ are the same vector space, then we don't need to prove that any property that holds for $U$ also holds for $V$.

But when we don't consider $U$ and $V$ are the same vector space, but they are isomorphic, then do we need to prove that any algebraic property that holds for $U$ also holds for $V$?

Comment: You ask a question "Do we really need to prove if two finite-dimensional vector spaces over F are isomorphic, then they have the same dimension?". But what does any of the rest have to sdo with it?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am sorry, but I just wanted to say sometimes we consider two vector spaces are the same vector space. If we consider two vector spaces are not the same vector space but they are isomorphic, do we need to prove they have the same dimension even if they have the same algebraic structure?

Comment: If we consider two vector spaces are the same vector space, then we don't need to prove that they have the same dimension because they are the same vector spaces and it is obvious.

Comment: If we consider two vector spaces $U$ and $V$ are the same vector space, any property that holds for $U$ also holds for $V$ because $U=V$.

Comment: $U\neq V$ but $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic. Then, $U$ and $V$ have the same algebraic structre. So, any algebraic property that holds for $U$ also holds for $V$ because $U$ and $V$ have the same algebraic structure.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I edited my question.

Comment: You have the right intuition here; the textbook is being very elementary and probably assuming that the reader does not necessarily have the skill to relate formal proofs to intuitive understanding of the axioms yet.

Comment: @user3716267 Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you my instinct was that this was very obvious and that a proof was scarcely necessary.

However, on reflection, perhaps something does need to be said. I would interpret "have the same algebraic structure" to mean that there is a bijection between the elements of the underlying sets which preserves the algebraic operations, in this case the $0$ element, the addition $+$, the negation$-$, and the scalar multiplications $\lambda\cdot$. There's no mention of "basis" here, I am not sure that it is part of the "algebraic structure" strictly understood. So I'd maybe feel obliged to prove that the bijection carries bases to bases - but it's very obvious.

Comment: ancient mathematician, thank you very much for your answer.